# Mozilla Firefox does not understand files with spaces

Tags: php, file, firefox, file-upload, download

I have files that i upload to the website that might contain spaces such as:

```
    file name 1.wav
```

It displays normally when uploaded, however when trying to download the file from Chrome and Firefox i get the following results:

```
  Chrome downloaded: file name 1.wav (perfect)
  firefox downloaded: file (bad)
```

name 1.wav was removed from name. Is there any specific functionality in PHP that will fix this problem in firefox?

CODE:

```
   <?= str_replace(array("'",'"'), array("&#39;","&quot;"), stripslashes($sFileTitle)) ?>', '<?=$f['fileExtension']?>'
```

This is what shows up when i inspect the element on anchor tag where file should be downloaded:

```
  <a title="file name 1.wav" fileid="254" class="docLink">file name 1.wav</a>
```

i use JQuery to redirect to the correct path.

FIX:

Adding urlencode($file) fixed it but arose a new problem. Now file with name

```
    file name 1.wav
```

turns into when downloading:

```
    file+name+1.wav
```

is it possible to replace + with space once downloading? urldecode didnt work

Solution:

if someone else having same problem here is how i fixed it:

instead of urlencode/decode i just did this:

```
 '"' . stripslashes($file) . '"'
```

and it fixed it

Comment: In your html put `urlencode('file name 1.wav');`

Comment: Firefox has no problems with spaces in filenames. Post some code.

Comment: header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");

Comment: `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Your file name with spaces.wav"');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
?>
```